# Is the Repository Pattern valid for a ASP.Net WebAPI project which just calls remote services

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, repository-pattern

I'm developing something similar to a service facade using the ASP.Net WebAPI. The objective is to create a RESTful middle layer between a backend system and a mobile application.

The code inside these service operations does not contain any logic which accesses data from a database. i.e. the EF framework, Linq to SQL, etc. Instead data is selected and updated by calling another set of remote services offered by a back end system.

I need to implement some sort of unit testing for each service operation. Almost all WebAPI unit testing tutorial I visited online contains data access via Entity Framework and a repository class just wraps a single EF entity.

Hence in my case

1. Does it make sense to have unit tests when there is no data access logic inside the service operations as I mentioned above?
2. If so is the Repository pattern the way to go? Please link an example which tests against a MVC project that accesses data via remote service calls if possible.
3. Am I confusing integration testing with unit testing?
4. If so should I just go for integration testing and forget about unit tests.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, you still have to test your layer and that's where the repository pattern helps you. In fact, your service layer seems to act like a repo itself. But your service will use it's own repository which will abstract the remote servers.
2. I won't link to an example , you can search for it, but things are VERY simple. It doesn't matter if it's mvc, mobile or whatever. The repository acts as a facade for anything storage related , in your case the remote backend. It will contain the code which call the remote services, but the rest of the app will use the abstraction i.e the repository interface.

3,4. IMO it doesn't matter how you call them, as long as you have relevant tests

You simply define one or more repository interfaces, and use those in your API. Test the API using Mocks or fake repositories. Those are the unit tests.

After that, write the actual repositories implementations which will deal with the remote services.